# Unity in Multiple Virtual Desktops

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-desktop, unity3d

I was wondering if anyone has found how to have multiple instances of the same Unity project open. I've tried using virtual desktops in Windows and it won't let me. I'm editing different scenes, but I'd like to be able to reference them both at the same time easily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can open multiple scenes at the same time in one Unity project and look into them at the same time.

Other more complex solution can be to close the Unity project. Make a copy of the Assets folder and the ProjectSettings folder. Then create a new second Unity project close it and pas into it the 2 folders in the correct place. Then open the 2 projects at the same time. In this way you are creating a brunch.